# Modifying an url in a MIME field

Tags: lotus-notes, mime, lotusscript

I have a Notes document with a field BodyMime where the Store content as HMTL/MIME is set.

In that field, I have some notes URL :   Notes://ServerNameA/DB.

I need to replace all the occurrences in the MIME field to put Notes://ServerNameB/DB.

I tried TeamStudio Configurator , he is able to do the change but I am losing all CSS and Format.

Anybody who have an idea what I can do ?

Some Example ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can try Genii Software [MidasLSX](http://www.geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/MidasLSX). It's a commercial product.

If you don't want to spend any money, you can use NotesDXLExporter and NotesDXLImporter classes to export, replace, and import back the documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a LotusScript agent to process each document, use

```
Session.ConvertMIME = False
```

before you get the NotesDocument. This prevents the loss of formatting as there is no conversion to RichText.
You can then

```
Set mime = NotesDocument.GetMIMEEntity
```

then iterate through the Mime.ChildEntities

```
Set child = mime.GetFirstChildEntity
While Not(child Is Nothing)
```

then use DecodeContent or create a NotesSession.CreateStream and use mime.GetContentAsText(stream)
eg

```
  Call child.DecodeContent
```

You can then search and replace in the child.ContentAsText and re-encode the mime-entity.

```
  Call child.EncodeContent(ENC_QUOTED_PRINTABLE) ' (1762) or use any other encoding scheme.

  Set child = child.GetNextSibling
Wend ' iterate through all mime-entities
```

finally remember to save your NotesDocument